# changing the indicatorStyle according the active tab in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my navigation bar, there are 3 tabs, i added `borderRadius` to the whole navigation bar and `Indicator`. What i want to achieve is

- When the 1st tab is active, both `borderBottomRightRadius` and
  `borderTopRightRadius` must be removed.
- when the middle tab is active, the `borderRadius` of the whole `indicator` must be removed.
- When 3rd tab is active, `borderBottomLeftRadius` and `borderTopLeftRadius` must be removed

Below images show the current scenario.

[image: when the 1st tab is active]

[image: When the middle tab is active]

[image: when the 3rd tab is active]

here is the code.

```
const Width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const tabBarWidth = Width - 30; 

const Navigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        S1: Screen1,
        S2: Screen2,
        S3: Screen3,
    },
    {
        swipeEnabled: false,
        animationEnabled:false ,
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: "white",
            inactiveTintColor: "blue",
            upperCaseLabel: false,
            scrollEnabled: false,
            inactiveBackgroundColor: "white",
            indicatorStyle: {
                height: null,
                top: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                borderRadius:10
            },
            style: {
                marginLeft: 15,
                marginRight:15,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 10,
                height: 30,
                borderColor: "blue",
                backgroundColor: "white",
            },
            tabStyle: {
                justifyContent: "center",
                width: tabBarWidth/3
            },
            labelStyle: {
                marginTop: -4
            }
        }
    }
);
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: one way i can think of is to manipulate the appearance via its `navigation.state`. like [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#customizing-the-appearance)

Comment: tried it. but it is not supporting for styling. don't know why.

Comment: i see. can you try adding this `borderRadius: routeName === 'S2' ? 0 : 10` to your indicator style after defining the `routeName` ?

Comment: tried. but not working. I think this option comes with `defaultNavigationOptions` . It can't be used with `indicatorStyle`